# User authentication by using SAP SF credentials

Tags: authentication, oauth, endpoint, sap-successfactors

I'm developing a web application that users have to login, Instead of my own authentication, I need to use SAP SuccessFactors authentication to check whether the user is legit or not, by using the username and password of SAP SuccessFactors. Is it possible? If yes - can you help me how to do it?

I checked the docs but couldn't found enough of how to achieve it.